# Can't Change Header Link Color

Tags: css, wordpress

I am currently trying to change the link color of a header and coming up short.

The default link colorin my CSS is blue but I want my entry header links to be gold. I thought this would be simple. Just define the link color to the div's header, but no matter what I do, the header link color keeps picking up the default link color.

Here is y CSSfor the global links:

```
/* Links */
a {
    color: #80D4F6;
}
a:visited {
    color: #80D4F6;
}
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
    color: #80D4F6;
}
```

Then here are the ways I tried to define the header links as gold:

```
.entry-title h1 a{
    color: #E9DB70;
}

h1 a:link{
    color: #E9DB70;
}
```

Neither worked. You can view the issue [here](http://noellesnotes.com/blog/).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you say "entry header" what are you referring to exactly?

Comment: The blog title. It's wrapped in <h1> tags class "entry-title"

Comment: you are talking about yellowish color that appears on pages when you click on heading?

Comment: Yes. For example, the headings on the sidebar are yellow. But I want to make the links of titles gold (but they're being turned blue because the global definition for links is blue).

Comment: I see it gold already, and your CSS is applied correctly, may be you should try to refresh your page.

Comment: i dont see .entry-title h1 a that class any where in css file

Comment: Please write html for understanding your exact situation

Comment: Confirmed the title is 'gold' in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer on Windows 7

Comment: @hushme it is there: http://noellesnotes.com/wp-content/themes/ribbons-and-clouds/style.css?ver=3.5.2

Comment: @paddy You mean that this issue is not happening for you on this page: noellesnotes.com/blog The title is blue for me on that page in chrome...

Comment: @Noelle have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: @noelle please check my answer it will solve your problem

Comment: @noelle I simply had not clicked on the link.  Once I did, it turned blue, indicating that you were not correctly styling `a:visited`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working. There is just a style overriding it.

You need to move your `h1 a:link` code **BELOW** the `a:hover, a:focus, a:active` and `a:visited` which is after line 337. You should also change it to just `h1 a` so that you don't have to define the `:visited`

If you don't want to remove the `:link` then use the code below

```
h1 a:link,
h1 a:visited {
    color: #E9DB70;
}
```

Comment: I just made these changes - moved h1:a link below the global definitions and also removed the :link so that I didn;t have to define visited. The problem is still ongoing... But others have said they're not experiencing the issue... This is so strange.

Comment: Not true, `h1 a` has a higher specificity than `a` no matter where it's located in the css document.  http://jsfiddle.net/hGFcC/

Comment: @Noelle you should manually add the :visited like I suggested and that will fix it. I just checked

Comment: @thgaskell you are wrong with what you said because `a:link` has high priority than `h1 a` http://jsfiddle.net/hGFcC/2/

Comment: @doitlikejustin Thank you! That finally fixed it! Sorry for all the trouble and thanks for your help!

Comment: @doitlikejustin using your own example: http://jsfiddle.net/hGFcC/4/, sounds like it should still be blue based on what your answer says. Noelle, I really think it was a cache issue since everyone else saw it gold.

Answer (score 1):

Set the :visited style as well, if you want it to remain yellow after visiting the page.

Answer (score 1):

Add `!important` selector to your `color`

```
<style>
h1 a {
   color: #E9DB70 !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use !important for use css.
Because sometimes other css change the design.
If you use !important then this css is used and effect of other css is not show.